# Bash/Shell -- Inserting line breaks between dates

Tags: bash, shell

Ive got data that comes in a file with multiple dates/times, etc...

example:

```
 12/15/19,23:30,80.2
 12/15/19,23:45,80.6
 12/16/19,00:00,80.5
 12/16/19,00:15,80.2
```

And would like to use some command that will automatically go through the whole file and anytime the date changes, it would insert 2 Blank lines so that i'm able to see more clearly when the date changes.

example of what i'm looking for the file to look like after said command:

```
 12/15/19,23:30,80.2
 12/15/19,23:45,80.6


 12/16/19,00:00,80.5
 12/16/19,00:15,80.2
```

What is the best way to do this through bash/shell command line commands?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F',' 'NR>1 && prev!=$1{ print ORS }
{ prev=$1; print }' file
```

- Use `,` as field separator
- If this is not the first line and `prev` is different from field1, print two newlines (`print` prints one newline and the 
  output record separator `ORS` another one)
- For each line, save the value of field1 in variable `prev` and print the line

Answer (score 0):

Since you're detecting patterns over multiple lines, you'll want to use `bash` builtins instead of programs like `grep` or `sed`.

```
# initialize variable
last_date=''
# loop over file lines (IFS='' to loop by line instead of word)
while IFS='' read line; do
    # extract date (up to first comma)
    this_date="${line%%,*}"
    # print blank line unless dates are equal
    [[ "$this_date" = "$last_date" ]] || echo
    # remember date for next line
    last_date="$this_date"
    # print 
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
# feed loop with file
done < my_file.txt
```

Here's the shorter copy/paste version:

```
b='';while IFS='' read l;do a="${l%%,*}";[[ "$a" = "$b" ]]||echo;b="$a";printf '%s\n' "$l";done < my_file.txt
```

And you can also make it a function:

```
function add_spaces {
    # initialize variable
    last_date=''
    # loop over file lines (IFS='' to loop by line instead of word)
    while IFS='' read line; do
        # extract date (up to first comma)
        this_date="${line%%,*}"
        # print blank line unless dates are equal
        [[ "$this_date" = "$last_date" ]] || echo
        # remember date for next line
        last_date="$this_date"
        # print 
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    # feed loop with file
    done < "$1"  # $1 is the first argument to the function
}
```

So that you can call it whenever you want:

```
add_spaces my_file.txt
```

Comment: If the file is large, `bash` is NOT they way to go. The `awk` solution will run much faster than a bash script. Not to mention it is easier to maintain and expand if needed.